# The alias "default" leads to an infinite loop. Aborting

Tags: node.js, version, alias, nvm

```
nvm use default           
The alias "default" leads to an infinite loop. Aborting.
```

.. the alias is pointing to v14.21.1

trying to reset the alias

tried to set it again ...

```
nvm alias default v14.21.1
default -> v14.21.1 (-> ∞)
```

Answer (score 1):

after checking

```
nvm alias
```

the following is found:

```
$ nvm alias
default -> v14.21.1 (-> ∞)
v14.21.1 -> default (-> ∞)
```

..
its fixed with using

```
nvm unalias v14.21.1
```

now I get this which is normal

```
$ nvm alias           
default -> v14.21.1
```